# (Create-React-App) Module not found: You attempted to import /node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

Recently upgraded to version 5.0.1 of react-scripts and in doing that I needed to re-add support for Node.js core modules by importing `NodePolyfillPlugin` into my react-scripts config and adding it to plugins. That did resolve the errors I was seeing but now I'm getting some new errors when trying to `npm start`:

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project directory.
```

[image]
The only reference to console-browserify is coming from the NodePolyfillPlugin. Does anyone know why this happening and how I'd fix it?

Comment: What does you project structure look like? Are you able to import npm modules from files within it?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this by adding the following when initiating `NodePolyfillPlugin`. If you need to use `console` I would imagine this wouldn't work:

```
new NodePolyfillPlugin({
  excludeAliases: ['console'],
});
```